# .NET ApiController: Custom model binding behaviour using [FromBody] T

Tags: asp.net, model-binding, json-deserialization

I use following code to deserialize an instance of `MyModel`

```
      public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] MyModel model)

class MyModel {
string a;
int b;
}
```

Is there away to enforce stricter model binding so that following input won't work?

```
{
"a":"someString",
"b": 4,
"c": "somethingIWantToCauseAnErrorWhenPresent"
}
```

Comment: i don't know what you want, but at least the model must be:``public class MyModel {
public string a {get;set;} public int b {get;set;} public string c {get;set;}}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own ActionFilter to lookup the request body and basing on your logic throw an exception

```
public class CustomValidationFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var bodyLength = context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Length;

            var buffer = new byte[bodyLength];
            context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
            context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);//do not dispose this streamReader
            var requestBody = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            var jsonBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(requestBody);

            if (jsonBody.Property("c") != null) // your custom validation
            {

            }

        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

Either you apply this filter globaly, in whole API like this (.net core 2.2):

```
            services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomValidationFilter))).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

or inherit from Attribute class and put it on certain action/controller

Comment: how would this look like for HttpActionContext (Not MVC)

Comment: this seems to be pretty tricky as it is not possible to set the stream position to 0 first..

Comment: `EnableRewind` is a exension method from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal` namespace, you will have to import it in the file in order for it to work